# LoopBack 4 REST API example for getting record with Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, loopbackjs, strongloop

i'm learning [loopback 4](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Getting-started.html), i have created model, repository and datasource, it also connected 
 to mysql and i can retrieve results from `http://127.0.0.1:3000/myapi/{id}`

in my default example getting by id is :

```
@get('/citySchedule/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Schedule model instance',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: {'x-ts-type': Schedule}}},
      },
    },
  })
  async findById(@param.path.number('id') id: number): Promise<Schedule> {
    return await this.ScheduleRepository.findById(id);
  }
```

However, i didnt found any tutorial for getting data with more parameters.

let say mysql table of `schedule` has contain column `id`, `city_name`, `city_code`, `date`, `task`, `item`.

for example, i want to get `"SELECT task, item FROM schedule WHERE city_code=123 AND date=2019-05-01"`

my question, how to write code to get those data at **loopback controller** ?
any example code...

my expectations, i can query from my api :

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/myapi/{city_code}/{date}/` to get data results or

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/myapi/{city_name}/{date}/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have generated your controller using loopback cli, you must have got another method in controller class like this

```
@get('/citySchedule', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Array of Schedule model instances',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {type: 'array', items: {'x-ts-type': Schedule}},
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  async find(
    @param.query.object('filter', getFilterSchemaFor(Schedule)) filter?: Filter,
  ): Promise<Schedule[]> {
    return await this.ScheduleRepository.find(filter);
  }
```

You can use this API to fetch more filtered data.

Considering your example

> SELECT task, item FROM schedule WHERE city_code=123 AND
>   date=2019-05-01

for this query, you need to hit the API like this.

```
GET /citySchedule?filter=%7B%22where%22%3A%7B%22city_code%22%3A123%2C%22date%22%3A%222019-05-01%22%7D%2C%22fields%22%3A%7B%22task%22%3Atrue%2C%22item%22%3Atrue%7D%7D
```

Here, the filter query parameter value is actually url encoded string for the below json string

```
{
    "where":{
        "city_code":123,
        "date":"2019-05-01"
    },
    "fields":{
        "task":true,
        "item":true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. but can't we create it without using filter but url like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/myapi/{city_code}/{date}/` ?

Comment: Yes you can, but for that you may have to add few custom handling within controller method. I can share that as well if you really need it